# How to show that lim $(1+1/n^k) = 1$ for $ 0<k<1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(1+\frac1{n^k})^n = e$  for $k=1$.

But for $0< k< 1$ how do I show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(1+\frac1{n^k})^n = 1$ for $ 0<k<1$?

Comment: You forgot a power outside of your parentheses.

Comment: Yes, so I modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^k} = 0$ for fixed $k \in (0,1)$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-\frac{1}{k})$ $ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^k}$ $ = 1 +0 = 1.$

---

[Note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$ i.e., there is the exponent $n$, and for $k<1$,
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n^k})^n =$ $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ((1+\frac{1}{n^k})^{n^k})^{n^{1-k}} = e^{n^{1-k}} = \infty  $ ]

Comment: Thank you!
Maybe you assume that lim$(1+1/n)^{a_{n}}=$ lim$e^{a_{n}/n}$. Is this assumption true?